# CakePHP 3 - validation 'add()' method is working with 2 parameters but method signature suggests there should be 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to do [alphanumeric with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320691/cakephp-validation-rule-alphanumeric-with-spaces) validation in CakePHP 3.5.13.

So I've added the following to one of my Table classes:

```
// src/Model/Table/SavedSearchesTable.php

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->add('search_name', [
        'alphanumeric' => [
            'rule' => ['custom', '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i'],
            'message'  => 'Alphanumeric characters with spaces only'
            ]
        ]);

     return $validator;
 }
```

This does exactly what I want - I get a validation error message if I enter a string that contains characters other than A-Z, 0-9 or a space.

However...reading about [Using Custom Validation Rules](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#using-custom-validation-rules) in the documentation all of the `->add()` calls use 3 parameters.

I've looked into the source (`vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Validation/Validator.php`) and the method looks like this:

```
public function add($field, $name, $rule = [])
{
    // ...
}
```

How can my rule work if I've passed an array for the second parameter, which it's treating as `$name`?

**Edit** : Someone has mentioned in the comments that there is a [fallback](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.13/src/Validation/Validator.php#L389-L393) for older code. Well, if I try and use 3 parameters (instead of 2) in the Model (note addition of `'custom'` as second param):

```
$validator->add('search_name', 'custom', [
        'alphanumeric' => [
            'rule' => ['custom', '/^[a-z0-9\' ]*$/i'],
            'message'  => 'Alphanumeric characters with spaces only'
            ]
        ]);
```

It now produces an error:

> Unable to call method "" in "default" provider for field "search_name"

Comment: `'rule' => ['custom', '/^[a-z0-9\s]*$/i'],` do a backslash s in the regex.

Comment: I think you've mis-understood. There's no problem with the regex and my code does exactly what I want - but I don't understand how it's possible. Because in `->add()` I'm passing just 2 parameters (`search_name` and an array). The signature for the `add()` function in Cake's source code expects the rules to be the *third* parameter. So I don't know how it's applying these rules, given that they would be treated as `$name` according to the signature of that method.

Comment: I see, you mean the signature and argument passing. It looks like they did a fallback check. Could be that in earlier versions of the framework this was used.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking at the code for the exact version I'm using (3.5.13). Inside the `add()` method - which is part of the CakePHP core code - it is using the parameters as defined. So I don't understand how my code works as the array I've passed in as the second parameter would be treated as `$name` (and not `$rule`) by their code.

Comment: There IS a fallback as supposed. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Validation/Validator.php line 396.

Comment: @MarkusZeller You can get links for specifc lines by clicking on the line numbers on the lef hand side: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.13/src/Validation/Validator.php#L389-L393**.

Comment: @ndm Nice feature. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Something's not right with that because if I change my code and pass a string as the second parameter (for `$name`) and leave the array as the third parameter (`$rule`) it errors: `Unable to call method "" in "default" provider for field "search_name"`. This was actually what prompted asking the question. I'll edit it to provide more context.

Comment: You are mixing up the two syntaxes, the second argument accepts multiple rules, indexed by the rules name (Not to be confused with the validation rule _method name_, that's the one passed to the `rule` option! The rule names are unique identifiers that are for example later used in the errors array), when using the third argument, a single rule is expected, and the rules name goes in the second argument, ie no additional nesting in the rule configuration. Check the examples in the docblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to this was provided by @ndm in the comments.

I'm writing out a full example in case anyone else has this problem.

It can **either** be written as:

```
$validator->add(
        'search_name', 
        'alphanumeric', 
        [
            'rule' => ['custom', '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i'],
            'message'  => 'Alphanumeric characters with spaces only'
        ]
);
```

**or:**

```
$validator->add('search_name', 
    [ // second argument is an array. This was how it was in the original question.
        'alphanumeric' => 
             [
                 'rule' => ['custom', '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i'],
                 'message'  => 'Alphanumeric characters with spaces only'
             ]
    ]
);
```

The following is given as a comment in Cake's [source code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Validation/Validator.php#L368) regarding how the `add()` method works:

> Adds a new rule to a field's rule set. **If second argument is an array** then rules list for the field will be replaced with second argument **and third argument will be ignored**.

Both of these have been tested and give the same result in CakePHP 3.5.13